# Ignore some statement in .proto for compiling stubs for certain languages

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-web

I'm using gRPC for communication between several services written in Python, C++ and RESTfull (https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway)

I have a gRPC server in Python, gRPC clients in Python and C++ and I have RESTfull service using  [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway). For all of them I use one single .proto file (to avoid duplication).

But `.proto` file contains several statements which I don't want to use for generation of stubs for particular languages. For example I don't need to import and use grpc-gateway statements like I mentioned in comments in following `.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package calculator;
option go_package = "github.com/grpc_api_for_software/grpc_client_web";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

import "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto"; // I DONT NEED IT IN C++

// I DONT NEED FOLLOWING OPTION IN C++
option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options.openapiv2_swagger) = {
  info: {
    version: "1.0";
  };
  external_docs: {
    url: "some_url";
    description: "gRPC-gateway some test";
  }
  schemes: HTTPS;
};

service Calculator {
    rpc NewTestSet(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (NewTestSet_response) {}
    rpc ChangeSettings(ChangeSettings_request) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
    rpc DoMath(DoMath_request) returns (DoMath_response) {
        // I DONT NEED FOLLOWING OPTION IN C++
        option (google.api.http) = {
            post: "/domath"
            body: "*"
        };
    }
    rpc ListToDict(ListToDict_request) returns (ListToDict_response) {}
    rpc DictToList(DictToList_request) returns (DictToList_response) {}
}
...
```

Is it possible to ignore certain statements for compiling code of `.proto` in particular languages?